# re-search-forward search for double and reverse quotation mark character

Tags: regular-expressions

Good afternoon. Difficulties with creating a regular expression for this function. Interested in finding a double quotation mark or back quotation mark. Attempts at use were unsuccessful:

```
(re-search-forward "\"\\|`" $z_poz t)
(re-search-forward "\"\|`" $z_poz t)
(re-search-forward "\"|`" $z_poz t)
```

The alternative character is followed by a back quotation mark. Thank you.

Comment: Your first attempt was correct (assuming you wish to search for either `"` or `\``), so your problem isn't what you think it is.  What is your problem?

Comment: Yes you are right, the errors were not in the regular expression

Comment: Thanks for editing Muihlinn, I couldn't insert a back quotation mark

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem has been left unstated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
"[\"`]"
```

for the regexp part.

It is easier to build regular expressions with `rx` or `rx-to-string`.

Here is a demo using `M-x ielm`.

```
*** Welcome to IELM ***  Type (describe-mode) or press C-h m for help.
ELISP> (rx-to-string '(or "`" "\""))
"[\"`]"
ELISP>
```

Comment: They don't "need" to use that.  What they did initially was equally valid.

Comment: `rx` is the way to go; you’ll soon get LTS otherwise.

Comment: As far as you know, the inverse of a character class doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

The function does work with the expression, the mistake was poor tracking of the position of the point. Below code

```lisp
    (defun otmKvhk()
      "Отметка выражений в кавычках
    Обрабатывается выделенный регион
    Отмечается только крайние кавычки, вложения пропускаются,
    начало соответствия 'bbo# ', конец ' #obb'"
      (interactive)
      (let ((n_pozRgn (region-beginning)) (z_pozRgn (region-end)) n_svpd k_svpd)
        (goto-char n_pozRgn)
        (while (setq n_svpd (re-search-forward "\"\\|`" z_pozRgn t))
          (let ((data (match-data)))
        (unwind-protect
            (if (setq k_svpd (search-forward (match-string-no-properties 0) z_pozRgn t))
            (progn (insert " #obb")
                   (setq k_svpd (+ 5 k_svpd))
                   (setq n_svpd (- n_svpd 1))
                   (goto-char n_svpd)
                   (insert "bbo# ")
                   (setq k_svpd (+ 5 k_svpd))
                   (goto-char k_svpd)
                   (setq z_pozRgn (+ 10 z_pozRgn)))
              (error "%s" "Не найдено соответствие!")
              )
          (set-match-data data)))
          )
        (goto-char z_pozRgn))
      )
```

Comment: n.b. `C-h f save-match-data`